# Test if two binomial number of successes are statistically different from each other

Tags: binomial-distribution, standard-deviation, ratio

I'm looking to compare two groups and their number of successes (on a hit/miss task) to see whether the difference is statistically significant. This is similar but slightly different to a comparison of *portions*, which is what most of the formulas show that I've found.

The formula I am trying to figure out is as follows:

> A critical ratio used to decide whether the numbers of hits obtained
>   under two conditions (or by two groups of subjects) differ
>   significantly from each other; it is obtained by dividing the
>   difference between the two total-hits scores by the standard deviation
>   of the difference.

I am stuck on what the "standard deviation of the difference" is. I know that the standard deviation of one of the groups would just be sqrt(npq), where n = number of trials, p = probability of hit which in this case is 1/5, and q = 1 - p. But what about the standard deviation of the difference?